# VBA Excel how to activate macro for sheet 2, 3 and 4 from sheet 1

Tags: excel, foreach, worksheet, vba

I have 3 workbooks in one folder.
 I use macro to copy each **Sheet1** in every workbook in that folder into my **workbook example**.
In my **workbook example** now I have 4 sheets named **sheet1**, **sheet1 (4),** **sheet1 (3),** **sheet1 (2).**

I want to use a button form so when I click it, the code (below) run for any other sheets except sheet one.

```
Sub Copy_Sum()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'Selecting the worksheets to loop through
    K = 1
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Skiping the sheet1
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
    'Counting the number of rows for automation
            rowscount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            temp = 0
    'add name
            Cells(rowscount + 1, 8) = "Jumlah"
            Cells(rowscount + 2, 8) = "Mutasi"
    'Looping throught the cells for the calculation
            For j = 2 To (rowscount)
               'Counting the number of cells which value greater than zero
                If Cells(j, 9) > 0 Then
                    temp = temp + 1
                End If
            Next j
    'Counting the number of rows for automation
            rowscount1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            temp1 = 0
            For i = 2 To (rowscount1)
            'Counting the number of cells which value greater than zero
                If Cells(i, 10) > 0 Then
                    temp1 = temp1 + 1
                End If
            Next i
     'Summing up the values which are above the current cell
     'and in Sheet1, this inclues negative numbers as well
            Cells(rowscount + 1, 9).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 9), _
                Cells(rowscount, 9)))
            Cells(rowscount + 2, 9) = temp
            Cells(rowscount1 + 1, 10).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 10), _
                Cells(rowscount1, 10)))
            Cells(rowscount1 + 2, 10) = temp1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I'm don't fully understand the macro code.
 This code was made by editing the code from NEOmen and I really appreciate it.
This is code supposed to automatically loop the code for each sheet except sheet1 but it didn't work.
I must run the code manually in sheet1 (4), sheet1 (3), sheet1 (2) to get it done.
I think I can edit it a little bit like what I wanted, but I can't. 
I got stuck in the end.

the code after revision from @chris neilsen @L42

```
Sub Copy_Sum()

Dim ws As Worksheet
'Selecting the worksheets to loop through
K = 1
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'Skiping the sheet1
With ws
    If .Name <> "Sheet1" Then
'Counting the number of rows for automation
         rowscount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         temp = 0
'add name
        .Cells(rowscount + 1, 8) = "Jumlah"
        .Cells(rowscount + 2, 8) = "Mutasi"
'Looping throught the cells for the calculation
             For j = 2 To (rowscount)
           'Counting the number of cells which value greater than zero
                  If .Cells(j, 9) > 0 Then
                  temp = temp + 1
                  End If
              Next j

'Counting the number of rows for automation
         rowscount1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         temp1 = 0

              For i = 2 To (rowscount1)
           'Counting the number of cells which value greater than zero
                  If .Cells(i, 10) > 0 Then
                  temp1 = temp1 + 1
                  End If
              Next i

 'Summing up the values which are above the current cell and in Sheet1, this inclues negative numbers as well

             .Cells(rowscount + 1, 9).Value = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, 9), .Cells(rowscount, 9)))
             .Cells(rowscount + 2, 9) = temp

             .Cells(rowscount1 + 1, 10).Value = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, 10), .Cells(rowscount1, 10)))
             .Cells(rowscount1 + 2, 10) = temp1
             'copy ke sheet 1

             End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: All the `Cells` and `Range` references refer to the ActiveSheet.  Perhaps they should be `ws.Cells` and `ws.Range`

Comment: @chrisneilsen ah didn't see your comment while posting my answer. If you wish to add it as answer, I'll delete mine :)

Comment: @l42 no prob, just leave it as is

Comment: woooo.. thanks a lot @chrisneilsen it really solved my problem. i tried to figure it out for about a week now but it finally finished with your help thanks again :D

if you don't mind i would like to ask. why i need to add dot to every cells and range to make it right? i can't understand even now when the code become right.
ah and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: woooo.. thanks a lot @L42 it really solved my problem. i tried to figure it out for about a week now but it finally finished with your help thanks again :D

if you don't mind i would like to ask. why i need to add dot to every cells and range to make it right? i can't understand even now when the code become right.
ah and sorry for my bad english.
since only one user can be mentioned once a time so i write another comment.

Comment: @AdityaNugroho You only need to add dot if you use `With Statement` as in my example. But if you'd take chris' advise you will need to add `ws.` in all the methods and properties you use instead of just the dot. See here on how to use [WITH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not referencing the object correctly.
Try fully qualifying your objects by using `With Statement`.

```
For Each ws In Thisworkbook.Worksheets
    With ws 'add With statement to explicitly reference ws object
        'precede all properties with a dot from here on
        If .Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            rowscount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'notice the dots
            temp = 0
            '~~> do the same with the rest of the code

        End If
    End With
Next
```